# Payment Details not showing up using Paypal rest API

Tags: node.js, paypal, meteor

Please take a look at following screenshot
[image]

I am using Paypal REST API. Now, you see there is no amount showing up. But I have provided all details as per requested in Paypal's documentation. Can you please direct me to how to get it working

Now, dont' you think that raises a serious question on paypal here ? For example, a website owner can show different pricing on the website and deduct different amount on the paypal, as the payment information is not at all visible on Paypal's website.

Comment: You must not be sending the request correctly with all the details.  Need to see a sample of the request you're sending to verify.

Comment: var samplePaymentObject={
     "intent":"sale",
     "redirect_urls":{
    "return_url":"http://localhost:3000",
    "cancel_url":"http://localhost:3000"
     },
     "payer":{
    "payment_method":"paypal"
     },
     "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
     "total":balance,
     "currency":"USD"
      },
      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    }
     ]
   };
 
 PAYPAL_API.payment.create(samplePaymentObject,{},callback);

Comment: I think the above text is unreadable. You can read the code here
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=50J5SSpm

Answer (score 0):

-RECURRING- payments

If you bothered to read the question you would see that.

The only solution is to go back to Paypal's oldschool APIs as this feature is broken for the new RESTful Paypal API when it comes to recurring payments.

If you want this fixed - feel free to contact them.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I do to create a paypal payment (server side) and display the product information using the REST API. Of course, this will not process the payment. [If you want to take a look at the entire process, check my gist](https://gist.github.com/LeCoupa/85e71a30eb51d2eae76b#file-2-meteor-paypal-api-rest-client-file-coffee).

**Note**: Do not forget to add the HTTP package.

```
Meteor.methods({
  'createPaypalPayment': function(product) {
    var payment, res, token;
    token = Meteor.call('getPaypalToken');
    payment = {
      intent: 'sale',
      payer: {
        payment_method: 'paypal'
      },
      redirect_urls: {
        return_url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/payment/paypal/execute',
        cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard'
      },
      transactions: [
        {
          item_list: {
            'items': [
              {
                'name': product.name,
                'price': product.price,
                'currency': 'USD',
                'quantity': 1
              }
            ]
          },
          amount: {
            total: product.price,
            currency: 'USD'
          },
          description: product.description
        }
      ]
    };
    res = Meteor.http.post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token.access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      data: payment
    });
    res.data['userId'] = this.userId;
    PaypalPayments.insert(res.data);
    return res.data;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey Julien - Thanks for the reply. The item_list doesn't seem to be working, because whenever I send item_list it thrown an error.

Comment: What is the error throwing? (you should see an error message in the response API)

Comment: You also need to add a details object to amount if you want to pass line items - see: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#details-object

Comment: Here's a sample: http://pastebin.com/SkH1sY5y

Again, a different format, it represents the HTTP Payload that will be sent to the endpoint

Comment: Keep in mind that using localhost for return and cancel URL's won't work.  At the time those will be triggered it will be PayPal's server using that value.  If PayPal's server redirects to localhost it'll be redirecting to itself, and you'll most likely end up with a 404 error there.